# NodeJS - Streaming directly to Azure Data lake

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, stream, azure-data-lake

I got the example bellow where im downloading a zip file using streaming. That`s working well.

But i have a challange. I need to download this file and send directly to Azure, without saving this download locally. Is it possible?

Look the code:

```
const { createWriteStream } = require("fs");
const stream = require("stream");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);

const url = "http://....../file.zip";
const fileName = "filedownloaded.zip";

const downloadStream = got.stream(url);
const fileWriterStream = createWriteStream(fileName);

downloadStream.on("downloadProgress", ({ transferred, total, percent }) => {
  const percentage = Math.round(percent * 100);
  console.error(`progress: ${transferred}/${total} (${percentage}%)`);
});

(async () => {
    try {
      await pipeline(downloadStream, fileWriterStream)
      console.log(`File downloaded to ${fileName}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Something went wrong. ${error.message}`);
    }
  })();
```

Should i use buffer to do that? I mean, how can i send this file to there? Someone do something like this one?

This is the code to create container, folder and file on Azure Datalake

```
const http = require('http');
var unzip = require('unzip');
const { DataLakeServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-file-datalake");

// Load the .env file if it exists
require("dotenv").config();

const sharedKeyCredential = 
     new StorageSharedKeyCredential(process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME, process.env.ACCOUNT_KEY);
const datalakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(
      `https://${process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME}.dfs.core.windows.net`, sharedKeyCredential);

async function CreateFileSystem(fileSystemName) {
  const fileSystemClient = datalakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient(fileSystemName);
  const createResponse = await fileSystemClient.create(); 
  return {response: createResponse, container: fileSystemClient} 
}

async function CreateDirectory(fileSystemClient, directoryName) {
  const directoryClient = fileSystemClient.getDirectoryClient(directoryName);
  const result = await directoryClient.create();
  return result
}

async function DeleteDirectory(fileSystemClient, directoryName) {
  const directoryClient = fileSystemClient.getDirectoryClient(directoryName); 
  const result = await directoryClient.delete();
  return result
}

async function UploadFile(fileSystemClient, from, fileName ) {
  const fs = require('fs') 
  var content = "";
  fs.readFile('mytestfile.txt', (err, data) => { 
      if (err) throw err;
      content = data.toString();
  }) 
  const fileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient("directoryexample2/uploaded-file.txt");
  await fileClient.create();
  await fileClient.append(content, 0, content.length);
  await fileClient.flush(content.length);

}

const main = async () => {
  const fs  =  await CreateFileSystem("filesystemexample2");
  const dir = await CreateDirectory(fs.container, "directoryexample2");
  await UploadFile(fs.container)
}

console.log("Starting ...")
main();
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use this code on UploadData, but i got an error.

```const fileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient("directoryexample2/uploaded-file.txt");
await fileClient.create();
await fileClient.append(content, 0, content.length);
await fileClient.flush(content.length);```


Error: (node:86818) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RestError: The uploaded data is not contiguous or the position query parameter value is not equal to the length of the file after appending the uploaded data.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you are just reading the string representation of the file buffer and feeding this to your `UploadFile` function. You could attempt to just read the the remote file as text:

```
const content = await got(url).text();
```

Then proceed to call your upload file logic directly after

```
const fileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient("directoryexample2/uploaded-file.txt");
await fileClient.create();
await fileClient.append(content, 0, content.length);
await fileClient.flush(content.length);
```

Comment: I have tried to do it, but didnt work. I got the following erro:

```(node:85967) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RestError: The uploaded data is not contiguous or the position query parameter value is not equal to the length of the file after appending the uploaded data.```

The file was created but with 0 bytes

Comment: I`m trying to find what is happening, if i find something, i will let you know

Comment: @Danilo could you update the original post with what you've tried based off of my answer, if possible?

Comment: I did it, put a new comment (i think that is not possible to modify the original post after i post)